# How to convert spark Streaming dataframe column into a Python list

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark streaming dataframe like below. I want to convert

```
+----------------+-------+-----------+-----------------+
|application_name|     id|syntheticid|          Journey|
+----------------+-------+-----------+-----------------+
|            test|   24  |   12392234|      Activation |
|            test|   24  |   12392234|          LOAD   |
+----------------+-------+-----------+-----------------+
```

1. How do I convert this to a normal dataframe?
2. How to convert the streaming dataframe column to a list? For example I want to convert the column journey into python list `['Activation','Load']`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please help on this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66099034/convert-streaming-dataframe-into-list-pyspark

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In terms of your first point, you're not asking the correct question. Since Spark 2.0, the APIs mostly overlap, therefore a Spark Streaming DataFrame is essentially the same thing as a Spark (SQL) DataFrame, albeit Spark Streaming DataFrame is unbounded.

> Since Spark 2.0, DataFrames and Datasets can represent static, bounded data,
>   as well as streaming, unbounded data.

Therefore, you should be able to perform majority of your necessary manipulations on your (streaming) DataFrame.

In terms of your second point, try to have a look at aggregation functions such as `collect_list()` and `collect_set()`. Try this code:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

>>> spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
>>> df = spark._sc.parallelize([
 ["test","24","12392234","Activation"], 
 ["test","24","12392234","Load"]]
).toDF(["application_name","id","syntheticid","journey"])

>>> df.show()
+----------------+---+-----------+----------+
|application_name| id|syntheticid|   journey|
+----------------+---+-----------+----------+
|            test| 24|   12392234|Activation|
|            test| 24|   12392234|      Load|
+----------------+---+-----------+----------+


>>> grouped_df = df.groupBy('application_name').agg(f.collect_list('journey').alias('collection'))
>>> grouped_df.show()
+----------------+------------------+
|application_name|        collection|
+----------------+------------------+
|            test|[Activation, Load]|
+----------------+------------------+


>>> python_list = [item for sublist in [row.collection for row in grouped_df.collect()] for item in sublist]

>>> python_list
['Activation', 'Load']
```

Comment: I have to perform multiple aggregations in streaming dataframe which is not supported. Thats why i am looking for options to convert the data into normal dataframe. Any other options available?

Comment: Your answer did help with my second question. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please give more details as to which aggregations are not supported and which version of Spark you're using?